# addListenerForSingleValueEvent keeps duplicating output

Tags: java, android, firebase

I use addListenerForSingleValueEvent to add value into the child "code" of the current user, but instead the data duplicated. 
[Here is the database before the coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha45j.png)

This is the coding for the addListenerForSingleValueEvent

```html
b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                final String UserId = mUser.getUid();

                mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
                final DatabaseReference currentUserId = mReference.child(UserId);
                currentUserId.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        user.setCode(riasec1);
                        currentUserId.child(UserId).setValue(user);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });




            }
        });
```

[Here is the database after the coding is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9BsG.png)Why is the whole user being duplicated instead of only value "code" inserted?

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
currentUserId.child(UserId).setValue(user);
```

you are saying `"add WHOLE user in to node with name 'UserId'"`.
In general you are fetching WHOLE User, updating one field and updating again.

---

So when would you like to update a child **without rewriting** the entire object u should pass node name, e.g.

```
currentUserId.child(UserId).child("code").setValue(riasec1);
```

In this call you say:

- find node with proper ID (`UserId`)
- find node `"code"`
- set new value (`riasec1`)